# How to expand variables in bash jobs list

Tags: linux, bash, shell

Is it possible to have the variable names in the bash jobs list (jobs command) expanded. E.g. I get job list such as

```
[1]   Angehalten              vi $file
[2]   Angehalten              vi $file
```

which refer to vi sessions with two different values of $file. Now I want to bring the vi window with a specific file to the front but don't know which job number it has.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Similar to Alex's answer but without all the paste and subprocess tricks. It worked for me on FreeBSD 10.0 with bash v4.3.30

jobs -p | xargs ps -p | tail -n+2 | awk '{print substr($0, index($0, $5))}'

Comment: What if you want the job #s retained?

Answer (score 4):

You can use `jobs -l` to get the PID of each, and then look them up in the output of `ps`, which will show the expanded string:

```
$ jobs -l
[2]-  6445 Suspended: 18           vi $file
[3]+  6473 Suspended: 18           vi $file
$ ps | grep vi
 6445 ttys000    0:00.03 vi x
 6473 ttys000    0:00.03 vi y
 6485 ttys000    0:00.00 grep --color vi
```

Answer (score 4):

Following command should work (tested with bash 4.2.10 on ubuntu 11.10)

```
paste <(jobs) <(jobs -p | xargs ps -p | tail -n+2 | awk '{print substr($0, index($0, $5))}')
```

output:

```
[1]   Stopped                 vi $A     vi a
[2]-  Stopped                 vi $A     vi b
[3]+  Stopped                 vi $A     vi c
```

The idea is same as Carl's - extract the command by process id

Comment: looks good, but for some reason it does not work if I put the line in a bash script file.

Comment: it works as function in .bashrc, but only if there is more than one process in the background.

Comment: That's because scripts are run in a separate subshell, which (obviously) doesn't have the same `jobs` listing as your current shell.  Is there a reason you don't want to use it as a function?

Comment: Here's a slight refactoring which works for a single background process, too: `awk 'NR==FNR { if (NR==1) next; c=""; s=""; for (i=5; i<=NF; ++i) { c = c s $i; s=" "; } k[$1]=c; next } { print $1, $2, $3, k[$2] }' <(ps T) <(jobs -l)` ... I hope `ps T` works for you, the intent is to get the processes which are attached to the current terminal with their full argument list.

Answer (score 0):

If you can try and expand the variables before you execute the command.
Maybe there is a way of doing this without ever writing to file.
If not use mktemp to start the temp file.

```
cmd1=sleep
echo "$cmd1 10 &" > /tmp/veryscary.sh && source /tmp/veryscary.sh
```

Answer (score 0):

```
jobs -p | while read pid; do ps auxwq $pid; done | grep -v USER
```

Comment: I'm nearly 100% certain that you are giving BSD style options to someone who specified a Linux system.

Comment: If you're referring to the options "auxw" to 'ps', then ... nope, those options work in linux. As far as I know they actually "work" in linux/*bsd/osx/cygwin/(maybe others???), that's why I use them, and I included them all out of simple habit. I quoted "work" because just maybe some of those flags are simply ignored on some platforms. As for cygwin, you have to use '-p <pid>' instead of '-q <pidlist>'

Comment: Well, they sure don't work on Ubuntu.  `dhoelzer@MON-01:~$ ps auxwq`
`error: unsupported option (BSD syntax)`

Comment: Hmmm ... bummer ... works in redhat/centos. Note that when using the 'q' in that list you do need to provide at least one PID.

Comment: Yah, the pid makes no difference.

Comment: @DavidHoelzer That must be an Ubuntu thing. It works for me on Debian and Arch Linux.

Answer (score 0):

Further to arj's answer but without the need for a temp file, how about:

```
cmd1=sleep
eval `echo "$cmd1 10 &"`
```